# Why is outreg2 not giving the descriptive statistics properly?

Tags: statistics, stata

I am trying to get the descriptive statistics on this code, but it doesn’t seem to work properly (as image shows). How can I correct it so I can get each statistic individually on an Excel file?
This is the code:

```
split estu_fechanacimiento , p("/" "/")
rename estu_fecha~1 dia_nacimiento
rename estu_fecha~2 mes_nacimiento
rename estu_fecha~3 año_nacimiento

destring año_nacimiento, replace
gen año_presentacion = periodo-18202 
gen edad= año_presentacion-año_nacimiento

keep if cole_cod_mcpio_ubicacion == 25386 | cole_cod_mcpio_ubicacion == 25878
keep cole_cod_mcpio_ubicacion edad estu_inse_individual punt_matematicas

drop if missing(cole_cod_mcpio_ubicacion)
drop if missing(edad)
drop if missing(estu_inse_individual)
drop if missing(punt_matematicas)
drop if cole_cod_mcpio_ubicacion <0
drop if edad <0
drop if estu_inse_individual <0
drop if punt_matematicas <0

rename cole_cod_mcpio_ubicacion codigo_municipio
rename estu_inse_individual inse
rename punt_matematicas puntaje_matematicas
label variable edad "Edad del estudiante al presentar el examen"
label variable inse "Indice socioeconomico del estudiante"
label variable puntaje_matematicas "Puntaje de matematicas del estudiante en la prueba ICFES"
label variable codigo_municipio "Codigo del municipio 25386 para La Mesa , y 25878 para Viotá"

summarize puntaje_matematicas inse edad, detail 
outreg2 using "resultados.xls", replace sum(detail) keep(puntaje_matematicas inse edad) eqkeep(N mean sd min p50 max)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzgFZ.png)

I tried changing the sum(detail) for stat(detail) and changing the type of the outreg2 file.